# How do I write a Hero like unlocking app for the Milestone (Droid)?

Tags: android, api, unlock

I just got my Milestone (aka Droid in the US) and want to write a simple app to ulock the screen touching one of the soft buttons, ala Hero. I looked into the Android API and could not find a helpful one, could someone enlighten me?

Comment: My (European) HTC Hero only unlocks if I press the Menu button twice. I think this is the same as my ADP1 does. Anyway, as hackbod mentions, there is no API for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no third party API for this.  The feature is a customization to the platform that HTC did for their devices.